# When do I scale services on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure, autoscaling, high-availability

I have created azure devops with a few organizations/projects in it. Do I need to scale or replicate it across different datacenters so all the developers across the globe can access it? When would I need to scale or replicate a service? Any references appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps is already replicated across multiple Azure Data Centers.  They did this after the south east data center hosting Azure Devops (then VSTS) went down for a few days, bringing down the service.  By going with a cloud provider, this is one of the benefits you (assume) you get.  Automatic (geo)replication/redundancy of SAAS products.  You don't have to manage this, but if something goes wrong, you have no control (or responsibility) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Manual intervention is not required for your Azure Devops organisation to be accessible to different developers accross the globe.

The on-premises version of Azure Devops can be scaled with [multi-server deployments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#:%7E:text=Azure%20DevOps%20on%2Dpremises%20can,that%20use%20SQL%20Always%20On.). However it's common to only deploy these servers to a single datacenter.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to scale or replicate it across different datacenters so all the developers across the globe can access it?

- No, you do not need to scale or replicate your data or projects to be accessable globally; however, some countries may have laws in place that prevent access to your project that reside outside of their region.
- The notion of renting someone else's infrastructure is that typically the infrastructure provider offers some degree of [replicating your organization's data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops#data-availability). Meaning replication of your data generally isn't needed.
- Applications/projects having failures or going down can happen and Microsoft's Azure documentation has suggestions on managing [backups and disaster recovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/framework/resiliency/backup-and-recovery). They also have services on [Site Recovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-overview) in general.

> When would I need to scale or replicate a service?

- When you want to minimize the effects of any single service having down time or being in a none recoverable state.
- When [Availability Zones](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/availability-zones/) becomes something needed in respects to the size of your projects. An example is needing to scale and replicate your organizations/projects across multiple data centers to ensure high availability is maintained.